# OpsCenter backend API for generating custom reports

Tags: csv, report, opscenter

I would like to know if we have any specific api's in OpsCenter which  would help in generating custom reports. 
The use case is:
I  am consolidating reports from different tools like App Dynamics,OpsCenter and others into one csv or excel sheet for which i would require any opscenter api which would allow me to do a backend call which would pull the required info for me from OpsCenter and then i can do some additional stuff and consolidate it along with other data in a csv or excel in an automated way.
Any api which would help me with backend Opscenter calls for reports data would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpsCenter API is fully documented at http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opscenter/opsc/opscApi_g.html

If the kinds of reports you're looking to generate involve metric data, you'll be particularly interested in the new-metrics endpoint: http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/api/docs/metrics.html#method-get-new-metrics

Otherwise you'll just have to wade through it to find what you're looking for. But the front-end is all driven through those api's, so anything you see in the web-interface can be replicated via the documented apis.